# Animation Bubbling issue using JSTween

Tags: javascript, jstween

I'm a bit new to the js stuff, but I have an issue that's driving me crazy. 
I have created a simple animation using jstween. My issue is when I click on the button that starts my animation, the animation works fine. If you keep pressing the button though it restarts the animation, that's what I'm trying to prevent.

I tried `stop()` and `stop(true)` but it didn't work. Here is my code below:

```
$('.mybtn1').click(function(){

    $('.box1').tween({
    left:{
      start: 0,
      stop: 400,
      time: 0,
      duration: 1,
      units: 'px',
      effect: 'easeInOut',

    }
    });

    $.play();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a static value of `0` every time the function is run. If the element has moved at all, then it'll jump back to `left: 0` before starting the tween.

Try passing in the current left offset when you run the function.

```
$(".mybtn1").click( function(){

    el = $('.box1');

    el.tween({
        left:{
            start: function() { return el.offset.left; },
            stop: 400,
            time: 0,
            duration: 1,
            units: 'px',
            effect: 'easeInOut',
        }
    });

    $.play();
});
```

You might need to mess with the syntax here. I'm not sure whether `offset.left` returns the value that you need (could be `el.style.left` or something).